# how to configure Angular routeProvider templateUrl to render properly

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have the following route configured in my Angular app:

```
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/Quote', {templateUrl: 'partials/tabcontrol.html', controller: 'TabController'})
          .otherwise({redirectTo: '/Quote'});
    }])
```

When the app runs, it looks like it has no problems locating the templteUrl file:

```
GET / 200 1.715 ms - 1138
GET /bower_components/angular-file-upload/angular-file-upload.js 200 3.964 ms - 49386
GET /app/app.js 200 4.496 ms - 5397
GET /bower_components/angular/angular-bootstrap.js 200 6.248 ms - 75250
GET /partials/tabcontrol.html 200 5.703 ms - 172
GET /favicon.ico 304 5.913 ms - -
GET /css/app.css 200 0.774 ms - 366
```

However, I see absolutely nothing on the page!.

Here is the tabcontrol.html:

```
<div ng-controller="TabController" class="container form-group">
    <h2>HHHHH</h2>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-inline">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Account information</legend>
            <label for="salesForceId">SalesForce ID</label>
            <input id="salesForceId" name="salesForceId" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="salesForceId"/>
            <label for="accountName">Account name</label>
            <input id="accountName" name="accountName" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="accountName"/>
        </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <tabset>
        <tab ng-repeat="workspace in workspaces"
             heading="{{workspace.name}}"
             active=workspace.active>
            <div ng-controller="TabsChildController">
                <br/>
                <label for="siteName">Site Name</label>
                <input id="siteName" name="siteName" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="workspace.name"/>
                <br/>
                <div ng-include src="'fileUpload/fileUpload.html'">

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend><strong>OR</strong> fill out the basic information below</legend>
                    <!--<label for="siteName">Site Name</label>-->
                    <!--<input id="siteName" name="siteName" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="workspace.name"/>-->

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label for="numberOfMainframes">Number of Mainframes</label>
                    <input id="numberOfMainframes" name="numberOfMainframes" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="workspace.numberOfMainframes"/>
                    <br/>
                    <label for="numberOfStorageFrames">Number of Storage Frames</label>
                    <input id="numberOfStorageFrames" name="numberOfStorageFrames" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="workspace.numberOfStorageFrames"/>
                    <br/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label for="numberOfUnixServers">Number of Unix/AIX Servers</label>
                    <input id="numberOfUnixServers" name="numberOfUnixServers" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="workspace.numberOfUnixServers"/>
                    <br/>


                    <label for="numberOfBladeCenters">Number of Blade Centers</label>
                    <input id="numberOfBladeCenters" name="numberOfBladeCenters" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="workspace.numberOfBladeCenters"/>
                    <br/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">

                    <label for="numberOfx86Servers">Number of x86 Servers</label>
                    <input id="numberOfx86Servers" name="numberOfx86Servers" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="workspace.numberOfx86Servers"/>


                        </div>

                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
        </tab>
        <tab select="addWorkspace()">
            <tab-heading> Add Site
                <i class="icon-plus-sign"></i>
            </tab-heading>
        </tab>
        <tab select="removeWorkspace()">
            <tab-heading> Remove Selected Site
                <i class="icon-plus-sign"></i>
            </tab-heading>
        </tab>
    </tabset>
    <br/>
    <button type="button" class="btn-primary" ng-click="collectValuesFromEachTab()">Generate a Quote</button>
    <!--<h3>Workspaces</h3>-->
    <!--<pre>{{workspaces|json}}</pre>-->
</div>
```

Here is the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>DC Quote</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-view></div>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="../bower_components/angular/angular-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="../bower_components/angular-file-upload/angular-file-upload.js"></script>
<script   src="../app/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the main angular app module:

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'angularFileUpload'
]).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/Quote', {templateUrl: 'partials/tabcontrol.html', controller: 'TabController'})
          .otherwise({redirectTo: '/Quote'});
    }])
    .controller("TabController", ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http) {
      console.log("This is TabController");
      var setAllInactive = function() {
        angular.forEach($scope.workspaces, function(workspace) {
          workspace.active = false;
        });
      };

      var Site = {
        numberOfMainframes: undefined,
        numberOfStorageFrames:  undefined,
        numberOfUnixServers:  undefined,
        numberOfBladeCenters: undefined,
        numberOfX86Servers: undefined
      };

      var addNewWorkspace = function() {
        var id = $scope.workspaces.length + 1;
        $scope.workspaces.push({
          id: id,
          name: "Site " + id,
          active: true
        });
      };

      $scope.workspaces =
          [
            { id: 1, name: "Site 1" ,active:true  },
            { id: 2, name: "Site 2" ,active:false  }
          ];

      $scope.addWorkspace = function () {
        setAllInactive();
        addNewWorkspace();
      };

      $scope.removeWorkspace = function() {
        angular.forEach($scope.workspaces, function(workspace) {
          if(workspace.active){
            var index = $scope.workspaces.indexOf(workspace);
            console.log('Active Workspace id: ' + index);
            $scope.workspaces.splice(index,1);
          }
        })
      };

      $scope.collectValuesFromEachTab = function(){

        $scope.quote = new Object();
        $scope.quote.SalesForceId = $scope.salesForceId;
        $scope.quote.AccountName = $scope.accountName;
        $scope.quote.siteCollection = [];

        angular.forEach($scope.workspaces, function(workspace) {
          //console.log("Site: " + workspace.name);
          //console.log("Number of Mainframes: " + workspace.numberOfMainframes);
          //console.log("Number of Starage Frames" + workspace.numberOfStorageFrames);
          //console.log("Number of Unix/AIX Servers: " + workspace.numberOfUnixServers);
          //console.log("Number of Blade Centers: " + workspace.numberOfBladeCenters);
          //console.log("Number of x86 Servers: " + workspace.numberOfx86Servers);

          var site = new Object();
          site.SiteName = workspace.name;
          site.NumberOfMainframes = workspace.numberOfMainframes;
          site.NumberOfStorageFrames = workspace.numberOfStorageFrames;
          site.NumberOfUnixServers = workspace.numberOfUnixServers;
          site.NumberOfBladeCenters = workspace.numberOfBladeCenters;
          site.NumberOfX86Servers = workspace.numberOfx86Servers;

          $scope.quote.siteCollection.push(site);
        });
        var res = $http.post('http://10.211.55.26:8081/api/dcquote/testquote', $scope.quote);
        res.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.message = data;
        });
        res.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          alert( "failure message: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
        });
      }

    }])
    .controller("TabsChildController", ['$scope',function($scope){

    }])
    .controller('FileUploadController', ['$scope', 'FileUploader', function($scope, FileUploader) {
      var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
        url: 'http://10.211.55.26:8081/api/test/files'
      });

      // FILTERS

      uploader.filters.push({
        name: 'customFilter',
        fn: function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, options) {
          return this.queue.length < 10;
        }
      });

      // CALLBACKS

      uploader.onWhenAddingFileFailed = function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, filter, options) {
        console.info('onWhenAddingFileFailed', item, filter, options);
      };
      uploader.onAfterAddingFile = function(fileItem) {
        console.info('onAfterAddingFile', fileItem);
      };
      uploader.onAfterAddingAll = function(addedFileItems) {
        console.info('onAfterAddingAll', addedFileItems);
      };
      uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = function(item) {
        console.info('onBeforeUploadItem', item);
      };
      uploader.onProgressItem = function(fileItem, progress) {
        console.info('onProgressItem', fileItem, progress);
      };
      uploader.onProgressAll = function(progress) {
        console.info('onProgressAll', progress);
      };
      uploader.onSuccessItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onSuccessItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
      };
      uploader.onErrorItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onErrorItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
      };
      uploader.onCancelItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onCancelItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
      };
      uploader.onCompleteItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onCompleteItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
      };
      uploader.onCompleteAll = function() {
        console.info('onCompleteAll');
      };

      console.info('uploader', uploader);
    }]);
```

What is even more interesting, is that when I choose to debug the index.html directly, everything shows up as it should.
However, when the app is served by the Node (whoch is part of the same project), the page is blank (but no errors of any kind)

Here are the Node routes:

```
app.get("/bower_components/angular/angular-bootstrap.js", function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile("bower_components/angular/angular-bootstrap.js");
});

app.get("/bower_components/angular-file-upload/angular-file-upload.js", function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile("bower_components/angular-file-upload/angular-file-upload.js");
});

app.get("/app/app.js", function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile("app/app.js");
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('views/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
});
```

Comment: I'd check the response in the *Network* console for the `tabcontrol.html` file. What you've listed above looks like a lot more that 172 B.

Comment: You've specified your controller twice, remove the ng-controller directive on your template

Comment: may i know what browser that you use ? IE11 & chrome sometimes behaving differently for cache control

Comment: I have removed ng-controller = TabController from tabcontrol.html.  I have checked the Network response - looks normal (304). I am using Firefox and Chromium on Ubuntu 14.  So far - no errors, but the page is still blank.